# How to get `Label::createWithTTF` to support RTL languages such as arabic

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-win32, arabic-support

Firstly, I'm using `Cocos2d-x v3.6`, `Visual Studio 2013` uses(UTF-8 without signature option) and `C++`.

When using `Label::createWithTTF` method to write Arabic text, It appear like the following.

[image]

The previous arabic text has not been written correctly, It was supposed to look like this `السلام عليكم`, and it also supposed the Arabic language belong to Unicode encoding.

My code:

```
auto label = Label::createWithTTF("السلام عليكم", "fonts/arial.ttf", 34);
```

**Is there is any way to solve that problem ?**

---

**Edit:**

I have applied what in this link [ [Right-to-left mark](http://notjustcodebutart.blogspot.com/2013/03/arabic-language-written-from-right-to.html)  ] and the result was disappearance the Arabic text as in the following picture.

[image]

**The code:**

```
auto label = Label::createWithTTF("\u200fالسلام عليكم", "fonts/arial.ttf", 34);
label->setAlignment(TextHAlignment::RIGHT);
```

The problem still exists.

Comment: You might think about changing the title of your question.  "Why isn't this supported?" is basically someone's opinion unless it's documented somewhere, and I doubt you really care about the reason.  "How do I use this function to do something?" is a specific answerable question that more people might be interested in helping with.

Comment: This may help: http://notjustcodebutart.blogspot.com/2013/03/arabic-language-written-from-right-to.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Thanks, but unfortunately, your solution does not solve the problem. I have been updated my question.

Comment: Just wondering, were you able to fix it?

Comment: @lightyagami: Unfortunately, No. But I don't know what happened to the new releases.

Comment: Thanks for replying back! 

I guess the only workaround is string manipulation for the Arabic data. My current requirement is a custom font + Arabic text as well. So I guess I would need to write a string parser. 
Using the latest Cocos2DX and it's the same issue as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Label::createWithSystemFont instead of Label::createWithTTF.
This solved my problem with RTL.

Comment: Thanks, but `Label::createWithSystemFont` uses the system default fonts, and do not use custom fonts.